# Daily maximum 8-Hour running mean/moving average

Tags: matlab, max, filtering, moving-average

I have hourly data and I want to do find the daily max 8-hour average. Basically, for each hour of the day, I want to do an 8-hour average. So take the average of 0:00 to 8:00, then 1:00 to 9:00, etc.), so I end up with 24 8-hour average periods (with some running into the next day of course). Then I need to take the maximum of those 24 8-hour averages to get the daily max.

The .mat file used can be found here: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/9e2dgm0imvr0hpe/tAUOtpZEEa

A note about the format of the file: The O3.mat file has a variable called O3_Sorted that is a cell array. It contains all data, sorted already. But the data contains information from more than one site (i.e. there is information from different places). The information for each site is sorted together, but in the code, when I try to find the 8-hour averages, I have to pull out one site at a time so that the averages don't run into the beginning of the data for another place.

Here's a sample of what things look like. I included one day for one site and half a day of another site. The actual file has a month of data for each of these sites and other sites as well. As you can see, sometimes, the data is missing. 
Column 1 - Site name
Column 2 - Date
Column 3 - Hour
Column 4 - Data

```
003-0010    2007-05-31  00:00   0.016
003-0010    2007-05-31  01:00   0.015
003-0010    2007-05-31  02:00   0.002
003-0010    2007-05-31  03:00   0.03
003-0010    2007-05-31  04:00   0.019
003-0010    2007-05-31  05:00   0.013
003-0010    2007-05-31  06:00   0.018
003-0010    2007-05-31  07:00   0.024
003-0010    2007-05-31  08:00   0.031
003-0010    2007-05-31  09:00   0.029
003-0010    2007-05-31  10:00   0.031
003-0010    2007-05-31  11:00   0.035
003-0010    2007-05-31  12:00   0.026
003-0010    2007-05-31  13:00   0.026
003-0010    2007-05-31  14:00   0.033
003-0010    2007-05-31  15:00   0.039
003-0010    2007-05-31  16:00   0.036
003-0010    2007-05-31  17:00   0.035
003-0010    2007-05-31  18:00   0.031
003-0010    2007-05-31  19:00   0.03
003-0010    2007-05-31  20:00   0.03
003-0010    2007-05-31  21:00   0.017
003-0010    2007-05-31  22:00   0.017
003-0010    2007-05-31  23:00   0.007
027-0007    2007-05-31  00:00   0.045
027-0007    2007-05-31  01:00   0.043
027-0007    2007-05-31  02:00   
027-0007    2007-05-31  03:00   0.038
027-0007    2007-05-31  04:00   0.037
027-0007    2007-05-31  05:00   0.034
027-0007    2007-05-31  06:00   0.034
027-0007    2007-05-31  07:00   0.038
027-0007    2007-05-31  08:00   0.044
027-0007    2007-05-31  09:00   0.05
027-0007    2007-05-31  10:00   0.054
027-0007    2007-05-31  11:00   0.051
027-0007    2007-05-31  12:00   0.047
```

Here is what I have so far:

```
for i = 1:size(O3_sites)
    I = ismember(D(:,6), O3_sites(i)); % Rows were the cell array O3_sorted has data corresponding to a certain site
    site = D(I,:);

    %% Convert O3 from ppm to ppb, 1ppm = 1000ppb
    x = 1000;
    y = str2double(O3);
    O3_data = bsxfun(@times,x,y); % ppb    

% Find size of array
[M, N]= size(O3_data); 

% Create empty array
O3_MD8 = zeros(N,M-7); % double

**% Do a loop to calculate the running mean
for j = 1:M-7
    A = O3_data(j:j+7);
    O3_MD8(:,j) = mean(A);
end**

% Find max from each 8-hour loop

end
```

After I get the 8-hour averages, how can I ask MATLAB to find the max for each 24 averages? Basically, get the max of the hourly averages.

Also, the method I'm trying to do now is a bit risky because I'm not using datenum and so if data is missing a day, I won't know. But I have no idea how to consider that when writing the code.

Comment: Can you please post samples of the relevant data only and trim your code accordingly? It's difficult to decipher what your 23808 x 24 cell array actually represent.

Comment: I put up the whole code because some people like to run it. I put stars around the relevant section. Basically, the actual data measurements are in column 17 and the name of the site it came from is in column 6. The part that is important is the for loop area, especially starting from "Do a loop to calculate the running mean." Hope that's helpful

Comment: Could you then post ten rows of column 6 and 17 and then delete any code outside of the stars, please? Everything else is irrelevant to the question you ask. You have to make it easy for people to understand and run it if you want answers.

Comment: `O3_data` ends up being `N-by-M` where `M=1` since `O3` is a column vector, so `O3_MD8 = zeros(N,M-7);` is an empty array.  Is there a typo or wrong variable somewhere near this code in the loop? Also when multiplying a scalar (`x = 1000;`) by an array, you do not need `bsxfun`.

Comment: Sorry it took so long. Had to convert to csv and other stuff. Anyhow, hopefully it's easier to understand now.

Comment: I think `y = str2double(O3);` might be a typo, meaning to be `y = str2double(O3_sites);`, but I'm not sure of your intentions... or maybe `O3_Sorted`.

Comment: @chappjc This was part of the code that came before this. I made O3 be the column with the data, so it's correct - I'm just converting units in that line and that requires doubles. I don't need bsxfun to multiply a scalar by the entire array? You mean I can do it directly?

Comment: You're right about M = 1. I've flipped them, but still getting an empty array for A and 0's for O3_MBD8. There's still something not right about that part of the code. i is the number of different sites because I wanted to do each site at a time. But I don't believe that's the correct way of going about it.

Comment: Set a breakpoint at `I = ismember(...` and step through.  There are some strange things going on here.

Comment: The issue is the part starting `for j = 1:M`. How would you do it? Just assume I did it completely wrong. Still pretty unfamiliar with coding in general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just use the `filter` function, though I assume you already got your data in a proper format (1D-vector)

```
hours = 8;   % size of hour window defining the moving average
movAV = filter(ones(1,hours)/hours,1,O3_data);
```

For the daily maximum you need to split your "hour"-vector and `movAV` in 24h brackets. Assuming you have one value per hour you could just reshape your result into a `24 x N` array:

```
%example
x = 1:240;   %d ata for 10 days
y = reshape(x,24,[])
```

then use the additional parameters of the max function to search the max columnwise:

```
% in this case the max is always the last value of every day
dailyMax = max(y,[],1) 

dailyMax =

    24    48    72    96   120   144   168   192   216   240
```

---

respectively:

```
dailyMax = max(reshape(movAV,24,[]),[],1)
```

Probably for your case the most convenient would be to use `findpeaks` which would directly output all local maxima (Signal Processing Toolbox required).

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know how to use the filter and had trouble understanding the documentation. But the max function just finds the max of the entire array. I need it to find the max of every 24 items. How can I do that?

Comment: Is there a way to do the filter using datenum so it reads through every 8 hours instead of generically every 8 entries?

Comment: @shizishan for the first comment: look at my edit. Regarding your second comment: I'm not very familiar with the datenum format, I've never used it, so I can't really answer that.

Comment: About the filter command. Do you know if it will average if there's missing data? Like if there's a blank cell, what does it do? Skip it? Count it in the 8, but treat the blank as a nan?

Comment: you should interpolate (`interp`) blank cells before. You need an equidistant time vector, otherwise it's not gonna work.